# Getting an extra border for select

Tags: html

My HTML code is like below

```
<select name="remindby" class="dropdown form-control">
    <option value="example1">Example1</option>
    <option value="example2">Example2</option>
    <option value="example3">Example3</option>
</select>
```

I am getting output like below

[image]

Why I am getting an extra border ?

Comment: Try `outline` property

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a browser selection border. Try out a few browsers to see whether your "problem" persists. Or you could add an input below your select and click on it to test whether the additional border disappears.

Answer (score 1):

It's Outline when you select or focus.
Please put the below code in CSS to remove that border.

```
select:focus{outline: none;}
```

Comment: Thanks @Keyur Gajjar. Your solution is not working.

Comment: Then it's not an outline issue can you please share your code with the working demo in a code snippet.